# jquery .find() method won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well I'm trying to make a sort of a collapse button, thing is when I press the button twice, the rotate function won't work anymore.

I'm not sure if it's the .find() method that isn't working or the rotate function itself.

Here's the jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/XgX5m/2/

**HTML:**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jquery-rotate.googlecode.com/files/jquery.rotate.1-1.js"></script>
<div class="info">
            <div>
                <div class="title">
                    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/phLHqY3.png"/></div>
                    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
                </div>
                <div class="infot">
                    Teckentrup - seit über 80 Jahren am Markt - ist bis heute der einzige unter den führenden Anbietern von Türen und Toren, der vom Brandschutz kommt. Wir haben nicht nur die gesamte Entwicklung in diesem Bereich mitgeprägt und begleitet. Die hohen Sicherheitsanforderungen standen auch Pate, als wir umfangreiche Kompetenzen in weiteren Feldern der Funktionstüren aufgebaut haben.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="title">
                    <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/phLHqY3.png"/></div>
                    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
                </div>
                <div class="infot">
                    Teckentrup - seit über 80 Jahren am Markt - ist bis heute der einzige unter den führenden Anbietern von Türen und Toren, der vom Brandschutz kommt. Wir haben nicht nur die gesamte Entwicklung in diesem Bereich mitgeprägt und begleitet. Die hohen Sicherheitsanforderungen standen auch Pate, als wir umfangreiche Kompetenzen in weiteren Feldern der Funktionstüren aufgebaut haben.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.info {
    margin:15px 30px;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:2px;
    padding:20px;
}

.info .title {
    display:flex;
    font-size:22px;
    padding:5px 0;
    border-bottom:dashed 1px #C0C0C0;
}

.info .title:hover {
    cursor:pointer !important;
}
.info .title img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.info .infot {
    color:#9C9C9C;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10px 0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.info .infot').hide();
    $('.info .title').click(function() {
        if ($(this).siblings('.infot').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).siblings('.infot').slideUp('fast');
            $(this).find('img').rotateLeft();
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.infot').slideDown('fast');
            $(this).find('img').rotateRight();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're getting an error from that "rotate" add-on.

Comment: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'angle' of undefined*

Comment: Can anyone suggest a better rotate method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That plugin you're using turns the original `<img>` tag into a `<canvas>`.  You can make your code work like this:

```
        $(this).find('img, canvas').rotateLeft();
```

Personally I would look for a better plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Pure CSS rotating, since you asked for a better alternative:

CSS:

```
img.rotateRight {
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.info .infot').hide();
    $('.info .title').click(function() {
        var img = $(this).find('img');
        if ($(this).siblings('.infot').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).siblings('.infot').slideUp('fast');
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.infot').slideDown('fast');
        }
        img.toggleClass('rotateRight');
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tacpyp0f/)

Comment: you could add `transition: transform .2s linear;` to make the animation more smoothly. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/tacpyp0f/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
Please use below code on fiddle

When you are open accordion then image turn into canvas so at time of close accordion you can get image that already turn in canvas

=============================
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.info .infot').hide();
    $('.info .title').click(function() {
        if ($(this).siblings('.infot').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).siblings('.infot').slideUp('fast');
            $(this).find('canvas').rotateLeft();
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.infot').slideDown('fast');
            $(this).find('img,canvas').rotateRight();
        }
    });
});
===================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

info is not a parent of img its grand parent . so, take child of info and child of info class child –

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.info .infot').hide();
    $('.info .title').click(function() {
        alert($(this).siblings('.infot').is(':visible'))
        if ($(this).siblings('.infot').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).siblings('.infot').slideUp('fast');
            $(this).children().children('canvas').css('transform', 'rotate(-90deg)');
        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.infot').slideDown('fast');
            $(this).children().children('img').rotateRight();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: could you please add an explanation of how this answer solves the posters question?

Comment: info is not a parent of img its grand parent . so, take child of info and child of info class child

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for this, working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o8r4yqfb/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.info .infot').hide();
        $('body').on('click','.info .title',function() {
            if ($(this).siblings('.infot').is(':visible')) {
                $(this).siblings('.infot').slideUp('fast');
                $(this).find('img').css('transform','rotate(0deg)');
            } else {
                $(this).siblings('.infot').slideDown('fast');
                $(this).find('img').css('transform','rotate(90deg)');
            }
        });
    });
```